# Sparkle Framework alternative for wxPython and Windows development

Tags: python, wxpython, sparkle

I create application on wxPython for MS Windows. It's a port of native OS X application I made before. 
In OS X application autoupdate of application is gracefully serving with [Sparkle Framework](http://sparkle-project.org/). (It detects application updates by reading appcast.xml stored on server, then does all update specific magic, checking signatures etc.)
Are any similar solutions exist for wxPython/Windows development?
Do you need such port to integrate it into wxPython?

Comment: Can you share wxPython OSX app which is using Sparkle? I'm having issues integrating Sparkle into my OSX app and it could be helpful to others, too.

Comment: @ddrscott yep, try https://github.com/vladignatyev/pastebotmurder

Comment: @ddrscott but the solution is too old, I'm not sure it works nowadays. Also this page lacks of documentation. Don't hesitate to contact me via e-mail or twitter, I'll help

Answer (score 3):

**wx.lib.softwareupdate**

A mixin class using Esky that allows a frozen application to update itself when new versions of the software becomes available.

This module provides a class designed to be mixed with wx.App to form a
derived class which is able to auto-self-update the application when new
versions are released. It is built upon the Esky package, available in PyPi at
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/esky.

In order for the software update to work the application must be put into an
esky bundle using the bdist_esky distutils command, which in turn will use
py2app, py2exe or etc. to freeze the actual application. See Esky's docs for
more details. The code in this module will only have effect if the application
is frozen, and is silently ignored otherwise.

Comment: Does [Esky](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/esky) supports [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org) freezed applications?

Comment: Esky is currently capable of freezing apps with py2exe, py2app, cxfreeze and bbfreeze.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at [WinSparkle](http://winsparkle.org/) - it's a "port" of Sparkle ideas for Windows, on top of wxWindows.
Binding it to your wxPython app should be easy (swig / ctypes).

I haven't checked WinSparkle in some time, but it seems to be active, and IIRC, there are a lot of forks with enhanced download support / features.